# Show an equation has 2 solutions

Tags: calculus

> Show that $2+\ln(x)=x$ has two solutions at $x>0$

that is equivalent to $2+\ln(x)-x=0$ which mean that there are two values of $x$ where $f(x)=0$.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to note that $f(x)=2+\mathrm{ln}(x)-x$ is continuous and note that:
$$f(\frac{1}{e^2})=2-2-\frac{1}{e^2}=-\frac{1}{e^2}<0$$
$$f(1)=2+0-1=1>0$$
$$f(e^2)=2+2-e^2<0$$
such that $f$ should have (at least) two zeros.

Note that this approach only shows existence of two solutions, not what they are.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f'(x)= {{1-x}\over x}$, $f'(x)=0$ i.e $x=1$, and $f'(x)>0$ for  $x<1$ this implies that $f$ strictly increasing between $0$ and $1$ since $lim_0f=-\infty$ and $f(1)=2$ there exists a unique element $x_0\in (0,1)$ such that $f(x_0)=0$.

$f'<0$ if $x>1$ thus $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(1,+\infty)$ since $lim_{+\infty}f=-\infty$ and $f(1)=2$ there exists a unique $x_1\in (1,+\infty)$ such that $f(x_1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Outline:

1. First define $f(x) = 2 + \ln x - x$ and note that $f(x)$ is defined only for $x > 0$ and is continuous for all $x > 0$.
2. Calculate $f'(x) =\dfrac{1}{x} - 1$.
3. Show that $f'(x) > 0$ when $0 < x < 1$, and $f'(x) < 0$ when $x
       > 1$.
4. This means that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing for $0 < x < 1$.  Therefore, $f(x)$ can have **at most** one zero in $(0,1)$.  Likewise, $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $(1,+\infty)$ and so $f(x)$ can have **at most** one zero in $(1, +\infty)$.
5. Use the Intermediate Value Theorem (twice) to show that $f(x)$ has **at least** one zero in $(0,1)$ and **at least** one zero in $(1,+\infty)$.
6. Steps 4 and 5 then tell us that $f(x)$ has **exactly** one zero in $(0,1)$ and **exactly** one zero in $(1,+\infty)$.
7. Conclude that $2 + \ln x = x$ has exactly two solutions.

Comment: You show that $f(x)$ has a maxima at $x=1$ but don't you also need to show that $f(1) > 0$ for there to be zeros on either side?

Comment: Using the Intermediate Value Theorem takes care of that concern.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x):=x-2-\log x$ $(x>0)$ satisfies
$$f(\searrow0)=\infty,\quad f(1)=-1,\quad f(\nearrow\infty)=\infty\ ,$$
and therefore has at least two zeros. On the other hand $f'(x)=1-{1\over x}$ has only one zero; hence by Rolle's theorem there cannot be more than two zeros of $f$.

Answer (score -1):

Why bother messing around with analysis at all? Let's solve for $x$!

$ 2+\ln(x)=x$

$ -2 = -x+\ln(x) $

$e^{-2} = e^{-x+\ln(x)}$

$e^{-2} = e^{-x}e^{\ln(x)}$

$-e^{-2} = -xe^{-x} $

Notice here that on the right-hand side, we have a equation of the form $y=ae^a$, where $a<0$.

To solve for $a$ (and ultimately, *x*), we can use the Lambert W-function, which is defined as the inverse of the relation *y*. (I.e. $W(ae^a)=a$)

**However** for $a<0$ the Lambert W-Function is in fact bijective, and precisely bijective. The two solutions:

$W(-e^{-2})=-x$

**and**

$W_{-1}(-e^{-2})=-x$

So therefore:

$x=-W(-e^{-2})$

**OR**

$x=-W_{-1} (-e^{-2})$

Addendum: 
Technically, if $-x ∈ (-1,0)$, then we must use the function $W_0(x)$ instead of the function $W_{-1}(x)$. But nonetheless there are two solutions because of the property of the Lambert W-function. It really isn't any different to solving an equation to the form $x^2=16$ and realizing that there must be **two** solutions, $x=-4, 4$.

Comment: Sorry I need to edit this. Give me a sec...